# Gluon Mobile's Billing Integration Using Out of Date Google Play APIs

Tags: gluon-mobile

When I try to publish a Gluon app that includes Gluon's billing library, and also the `com.android.vending.BILLING` permission, I get the following error:

> Release uses an old version of Google Play Billing.

If I comment out the `com.android.vending.BILLING` permission, I am able to upload the app successfully, but billing is not enabled.

I am including the Gluon Attach for billing in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
    <artifactId>in-app-billing</artifactId>
    <version>${attach.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there a special flag that I need to enable to tell Gluon to use the current version of Google Play Billing?  Or do I need to include something else in my pom.xml?

Comment: There is no implementation for Android yet of the [in-app-billing](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/tree/master/modules/in-app-billing) service, only iOS for now. There was one with the old Charm Down, but that hasn't been ported yet to Attach.

Comment: Is there any ETA on when we might expect support for Google Play Billing in Gluon?